# Is it possible do shape inference using the TensorFlow C++ API without running the TensorFlow graph?

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I am wrapping TensorFlow in an external tool that needs to know the size of the outputs before the graph is run. The `tensorflow::GraphDef` is loaded from disk in C++.

I could run the graph for a single iteration and read the output shapes, but this might amount to a lot of processing just for reading the shapes.

One could imagine feeding inputs to a graph, propagate only shape information to the output nodes and read it from there, but I haven't been able to find a way to do so.

Is it possible do shape inference using the TensorFlow C++ API without running the TensorFlow graph?

Comment: Does the C++ API actually allow you to allocate the outputs yourself?

Comment: No. I am wrapping TensorFlow in an external tool that needs to know the size of the outputs before running the graph. I have updated the answer to reflect this. Thanks for the input

Comment: In general the graph may have variable output shapes, right? People can export the most refined static shape information as node attributes: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Graph#as_graph_def

Otherwise re-building the graph with the C++ API would call the shape functions (running it may not be necessary).

Comment: What do you mean by "re-building the graph" @AllenLavoie? Can you somehow get the shape information using the C++ graphdef builder?

Comment: By rebuilding I mean looping over the GraphDef in topological order, seeing an AddOp and adding a new AddOp to the graph using the C++ API. I wouldn't recommend it; exporting with shapes (`add_shapes=True` in my link above) sounds much more pleasant. It's worth noting though that most graphs have a dynamic batch size, so often the output size depends on the fed inputs rather than the graph itself. In which case you need to do [something like Grappler to specialize for feeds+fetches](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/grappler/costs/graph_properties.h)

Comment: Thanks for your input! If you write up your suggestions I'll accept it as an answer.